# Reading data form a .txt file and adding it to my Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I've been working on a school assignment for a while and I have noticed I need a little help finishing it up. Specifically, I need help converting/importing a FlatFile.txt into my normalized DataBase in .

My flatfile has many rows, and in each row there are many attributes separated by a ' | '.

How can I add each line and take every element in the line to its unique corresponding attributes in my DataBase (assuming I already have my connection with my Database established)?

I know I might need to use something like:
hint*: comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname); 
How can make the first element of .txt file equal to firstname?

I hope this made sense.

Here is what I have so far:

```
string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathString);

string[][] myRecords = new string[lines.Count() + 1][];
int k = 1;

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (myRecords[k] == null)
        {
            myRecords[k] = new string[values.Length + 1];
        }

        myRecords[k][i] = values[i];
        Console.WriteLine(myRecords[k][i]);
    }
    k++;
```

Comment: Your code looks good so far, now add the SQL part. You have to assume a fixed relationship between fields in your .txt file and columns in your database.

Comment: should I write to the Database inside the Foreach or do that separately?

Comment: sorry for the ignorance, could you show me? I am having some syntax issues.

Comment: The exact code depends a lot on the API used to access the database. Update your question with the things you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add each item from a line to a corresponding name in the database, by using it's position in the line; something like:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", values[i]);
```

*(Note: The exact syntax needed here will depend on what you use for this, but I'm assuming you'll be able to figure that part out).*

...However, for something like that to work, you'll want to change the code parsing the line and remove `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntrie`, since that will affect the resulting number of data-parts from each line.

An example:

```
var line  = "one|two|||five|six";

// Will produce: {one, two, five, six}
var nonEmptyValues = line.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Will produce {one, two, null, null, five, six}
var allValues = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });
```

The latter will allow your resulting array (`values` in your code) to always contain the correct number of "columns", which should make mapping from positions to DB column names easier.